# 8thWall ceased working for me

Tags: 8thwall-xr

I've just opened up an 8th Wall project that worked previously and now I'm getting error in initiailisation:

> ```
> (Filename: <b9c56817a7524cff94174dec8363ae2f> Line: 0)
> ```
>
> 08-08 17:13:12.105 4187-4246/? W/Unity: Attempting to render from camera 'Main Camera' that is currently being used to render. Create a copy of the camera (Camera.CopyFrom) if you wish to do this.
>
> ```
> (Filename:  Line: 2850)
> ```
>
> 08-08 17:13:12.135 4187-4246/? E/Unity: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>         at XRInternal.XRNativeBridge.XRGetCurrentReality () [0x00000] in :0 
>         at XRInternal.XRNativeBridge.GetCurrentRealityXR () [0x00000] in :0 
>         at XRController.GetCurrentReality () [0x00028] in :0 
>         at XRController.GetLightExposure () [0x00000] in :0 
>         at XRLightController.Update () [0x00011] in :0

```
(Filename: <b9c56817a7524cff94174dec8363ae2f> Line: 0)
```

08-08 17:13:12.138 4187-4246/? E/Unity: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
      at XRInternal.XRNativeBridge.XRGetCurrentReality () [0x00000] in :0 
      at XRInternal.XRNativeBridge.GetCurrentRealityXR () [0x00000] in :0 
      at XRController.GetCurrentReality () [0x00028] in :0 
      at XRController.GetCameraIntrinsics () [0x0001c] in :0 
      at XRVideoController.Update () [0x0000c] in :0

```
(Filename: <b9c56817a7524cff94174dec8363ae2f> Line: 0)
```

08-08 17:13:12.141 4187-4246/? E/Unity: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
      at XRInternal.XRNativeBridge.XRGetCurrentReality () [0x00000] in :0 
      at XRInternal.XRNativeBridge.GetCurrentRealityXR () [0x00000] in :0 
      at XRController.GetCurrentReality () [0x00028] in :0 
      at XRController.GetCameraPosition () [0x00000] in :0 
      at XRCameraController.Update () [0x00028] in :0

Comment: Is there any extra information you can provide about your project? Does the sample application on the 8th Wall GitHub page crash for you as well? If so, what device are you running on? What OS version is this device?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up rebuilding the application from scratch while omitting my personal XR prefabs and scripts and that fixed it. I don't know exactly what is the issue but I suspect it is my attempt to make the wrap the XRController with a singleton for easier access.
Important Tip: When you're making changes and messing with a fragile black box system like XR, be careful and test your app with every iteration.